# Katalon Studio to call custom keyword from other custom keyword

Tags: groovy, katalon-studio

I have 2 `CustomKeywords`, located in the same package in `Katalon Studio` project. I try to call one custom keyword from the other one. This code isn’t working in this case:

```
CustomKeywords.'mypack.myclass.mymethod'()
```

Keyword, which should be called:

```
package uploadFile

import static com.kms.katalon.core.checkpoint.CheckpointFactory.findCheckpoint
import static com.kms.katalon.core.testcase.TestCaseFactory.findTestCase
import static com.kms.katalon.core.testdata.TestDataFactory.findTestData
import static com.kms.katalon.core.testobject.ObjectRepository.findTestObject

import com.kms.katalon.core.annotation.Keyword
import com.kms.katalon.core.checkpoint.Checkpoint
import com.kms.katalon.core.cucumber.keyword.CucumberBuiltinKeywords as CucumberKW
import com.kms.katalon.core.mobile.keyword.MobileBuiltInKeywords as Mobile
import com.kms.katalon.core.model.FailureHandling
import com.kms.katalon.core.testcase.TestCase
import com.kms.katalon.core.testdata.TestData
import com.kms.katalon.core.testobject.TestObject
import com.kms.katalon.core.webservice.keyword.WSBuiltInKeywords as WS
import com.kms.katalon.core.webui.keyword.WebUiBuiltInKeywords as WebUI
import java.awt.Robot
import java.awt.Toolkit
import java.awt.datatransfer.StringSelection
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent

import com.kms.katalon.core.annotation.Keyword
import com.kms.katalon.core.testobject.TestObject
import com.kms.katalon.core.webui.keyword.WebUiBuiltInKeywords as WebUI
import internal.GlobalVariable

class upload2Files {
    @Keyword
    def upload(TestObject to, String filePath , String file , String file2) {
        WebUI.click(to)
        StringSelection ss = new StringSelection("\""+filePath+"\" " +"\""+ file +"\" "+ file2 );
        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(ss, null);
        Robot robot = new Robot();
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL)
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
    }
}
```

Other keyword, where I try to call it:

```
(new uploadFile.upload2Files()).upload(findTestObject('Object Repository/validateFile/input_originalFile'), (d_directory.toString() + '\\') + detachedTXT1, (d_directory.toString() + '\\') + detachedTXT2)
```

Error message:

```
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerInvocationException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: uploadFile.upload2Files.upload() is applicable for argument types: (com.kms.katalon.core.testobject.TestObject, java.lang.String, java.lang.String) values
```

Comment: your function call should pass three strings. you are only passing two

Comment: @dynamo : I fixed method call, but got still the same error.

Answer (score 2):

I will explain on the example "(new packagename.classname()).methodname()"

I have keyword1:

```java
package closeAplication

import...

public class closeApp {
    @Keyword
    public void cmdAdbCloseApp(String ApplicationID){
        String CMDclose = ('adb shell am force-stop ' + ApplicationID)
        println ('This CMD Windows command will be executed: ' + CMDclose)
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec(CMDclose)
    }
}
```

I will use keyword1 in the test case:

```java
def ApplicationID = (GlobalVariable.ApplicationIDds)
CustomKeywords.'closeAplication.closeApp.cmdAdbCloseApp'(ApplicationID)
```

I want to write another keyword2 and call inside keyword1:

```java
package runAppInMobile

import ...

public class runAppClass {
    @Keyword
    public void runApp (String ApplicationID){
        new closeAplication.runAppClass().cmdAdbCloseApp(ApplicationID) //here's the call of the above keyword1
        Mobile.startExistingApplication(ApplicationID)
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

(new  packagename.classname()).methodname()